# Почему в одном случае цикл работает, а в другом нет?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class DemoFor
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a, b;

        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for ( a ; a < b; a++)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;

class DemoFor
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a, b;

        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for ( a = a ; a < b; a++)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не надо "обязательно инициализировать".

```
for (; a < b; a++)
```

[iteration-statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

> All the sections of the `for` statement are optional.

Все разделы оператора `for` являются необязательными. (и могут быть пустыми)

Comment: Спасибо, огромное )

Comment: @twintwinterrors Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: сделано )))))))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант цикл использовать можно таким образом (не указывая инициализации в 1-м аргументе).

```
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.Write("Input A: ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("\nInput B: ");
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (; a < b; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
```